# Creating a WordPress post with tags with XMLRPC

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I cannot seem to find the appropriate documentation or make work the adding of tags into a WordPress post. The posting works just fine, but no amount of playing around seems to be able to get a post to appear with tags on it.

Here is what I am trying:

```
import xmlrpc.client 
data = {'post_title': title, 'post_content': content, 'post_date': date_created, 'post_thumbnail': int(id), 'custom_fields': custom_fields,  'post_status': 'publish', 'post_tag': tags  }
post_id = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(wp_url).wp.newPost(blog_id, wp_username, wp_password, data)
```

Post works, I get that result expected, but I cannot find a way to include tags in my posting. I've tried many keys including `'mt_keywords'`, `'tags'`.

There is additionally a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585307/publish-a-post-using-xml-rpc-wordpress-api-and-python-with-category). But it appears that if I try to use something along the lines of:

```
‘terms_names’:{‘post_tag’:["blah", "random new tag"]}
```

I can only get working if the tag's **already exist**. But I cannot find a way to add a tag from the API. How can I make this work or use the API to first add tags. I have found nothing in the documentation that allows me to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tagging Posts via Wordpress XMLRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731790/tagging-posts-via-wordpress-xmlrpc)

Comment: @cabrerahector I wish it was, but the link you suggest has little / no relevance. For a start this is in python, not java.